# jQuery Mobile disable page fade before slide transition

Tags: jquery-mobile

Quite simple, I have a link to a secondary page with `data-transition="slideup"`. That page slides up when opened and down when closed fine, but upon clicking the link itself, the current page fades out before the new page slides up. Similarly, when closing the secondary page, it slides down and then the other page fades in.

Can I disable this fade? I just want the secondary page to slide over the top of the current page.

Comment: The fade hides the scrolltop needed to add pages at top 0.

Comment: Can I not disable the scroll as well?

Comment: I'm not sure if JQM always scrolls to the top, because if your page was smaller than the screen height, you probably would not need the scrollTop. However if the page is longer, I'm not sure. I'm not the greatest fan of it either, but... alas. Have a look at [mpdtunes](https://github.com/dcarrith/mpdtunes). The developer wrote some really nice custom transitions to go with JQM. Maybe this gets you in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the CSS transition definitions. I ran into this same problem. If you edit the CSS transitions (transformations), then you should be able to get the desired effect you're looking for.

The transitions are defined as `<transition name>.in` or `.out`. You can find them in the structure CSS file. For jQuery Mobile 1.4.2, they would be defined in `jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.2.css`.

Here's a definition of the slideup (in and out) definitions:

`.slideup.out {
        -webkit-animation-name: fadeout;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 100ms;
        -moz-animation-name: fadeout;
        -moz-animation-duration: 100ms;
        animation-name: fadeout;
        animation-duration: 100ms;
    }
    .slideup.in {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        -webkit-animation-name: slideinfrombottom;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 250ms;
        -moz-transform: translateY(0);
        -moz-animation-name: slideinfrombottom;
        -moz-animation-duration: 250ms;
        transform: translateY(0);
        animation-name: slideinfrombottom;
        animation-duration: 250ms;
    }`

(there are also `reverse` versions for these definitions).

All you need to do is modify these CSS transformations to get the desired effect. Notice how there are defined animation names: `slideinfrombottom`? These are pre-defined `@keyframes` in the same CSS file.

Modifying everything here should give you everything you need to tweak and tune the page transitions in jQuery Mobile.

Important note: jQuery Mobile will not fire the `in` transition until the `out` transition is completed. If you'd like to tweak that as well, that's a completely different matter. There is code present in 1.4.2 that I saw directly address concurrent and simultaneous transitions, but I didn't explore it thoroughly.